# Вывести случайного пользователя противоположного пола

Tags: php, mysql

Возникла такая задача: Нужно выводить на странице рандомно по одному пользователю противоположного пола.

Не могу придумать как выбирать пользователя с противоположным полом рандомно.

В базе записи о пользователях хранятся в таблице `user` , о поле в ячейке `pol` - 0 = женщина. 1 = мужчина.

Я думал все это реализовать так:

```
//определяем пол пользователя и исходя из этого устанавливаем ему вывод противоположного
if ($user['pol'] == 1)$otbor = 0;
if ($user['pol'] == 0)$otbor = 1;

$koll = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `pol` = '$otbor'",$db);
while ($uss = mysql_fetch_assoc($koll))
   {
          //здесь данные о пользователе противоположного пола
   }
```

Но ведь нужно рандомно выводить пользователей, а так я только вывел одного пользователя противоположного пола.

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: можно упростить SQL: `"SELECT * FROM user WHERE pol <> '" . $user['pol'] . "'"`

Comment: да это не имеет значения

Comment: @Денис Ага! Так я и поверил, что пользователь противоположного  пола был выбран случайно!:)

Comment: *0 = женщина. 1 = мужчина* — ох, попадётесь вы в цепкие лапки феминисток! и вообще, всего **два** пола — это ж как нетолерантно!

Comment: да, для пола есть как минимум три значения 0-не указано, 1- муж, 2- жен. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_5218

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте `ORDER BY RAND()` в SQL

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `pol` <> '" . $user['pol'] . "' ORDER BY RAND()",$db);
```